# Is this still a sketch?

Tags: drawing, sketching

I have made two drawings and I copied both of them from someone on deviantART. These are my first drawings so I have very little knowledge about the subject. The first drawing (Stark/Iron Man), was done in roughly 6 hours. While the second one (Dr. Strange) took 9 months because I was very busy and was only drawing on it on very rare occasions.

[image]
[image]

I have searched around for the meaning of a sketch and it says that a sketch is supposed to be quick drawn. If these drawings are not considered as a sketch. What would they be considered as?

Credits to yinyuming from deviantART for the original Dr. Strange drawing. Wasn't able to find the one for the iron man drawing anymore.

Comment: You used the word yourself: they are… drawings. Pencil drawings, by the look of it. Sketches are indeed generally something that you make quickly, either because you don't have time to draw it properly with details, or because exactness and detail isn't necessary for your purposes.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet please leave that as an answer so others can vote on it. Comments shouldn't be used for answers, plus the 4 upvotes your comment received would earn you rep if its an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no definite line between something being a sketch and being a drawing. A drawing is generally considered to be a sketch if it is to be used to create another piece. Usually a sketch is rougher, with less detail than the finished piece.

Only you can decide if it's still a sketch. Being a sketch doesn't make something less worthy as a piece of art. Sometimes a sketch can be the finished piece. Sketches by famous artists have been sold for tens of thousands of dollars!

Call it a sketch, a pencil drawing, a pencil portrait. It doesn't really matter, since there are no exact terms.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch is an illustration of existing facts, ideas or methods or all of them. It's made to prepare something which is planned or at least thought to be possible.

These drawings are in frames, but they can still be sketches. Only you know if they are made as a preparation for something or are they final products.

Probably you are interested, do we here think that your drawing ability is enough for something to be published? If I guessed right, these can be considered to be sketches which demonstrate what your pencil in your hands can output.  That question of course need an answer. My opion and that's only an opinion = Yes.

Another opinion: Get original. Then you're an artist.